# ISerializationCallbackReceiver Interface and Serialization in Unity

Tags: c#, serialization, dictionary, unity-game-engine

My problem started when I began using the `ISerializationCallbackReciever` to create a `Serializable Dictionary` in Unity, It worked fine for most of my classes but when I nested 2 `Serializable Dictionaries` I started getting trouble with Enumeration.

I believe it was during `OnBeforeSerialize` where the dictionary had trouble adding `KeyValue Pairs` after a certain count, I solved this by defining a dictionary property and used it to access the data in my keys and lists, so to be a bit clearer, I was working on a `Custom Inspector` which had to variations of keys, so I thought using a `Serializable Dictionary` would work best since I have more than a hundred variations, what my object does is it collects data from my assets and divides that data depending on the key I gave it.

the code for my Scriptable Object:

```
[System.Serializable]
public class LetterDataObject : ScriptableObject
{
    [SerializeField]
    public DictionaryOfLettersData lettersData;

    [SerializeField]
    public bool isText = false;

    [SerializeField]
    public bool [] folds;
}

[System.Serializable]
public class Letter_Data
{
    [SerializeField]
    public string letterText;
    [SerializeField]
    public Sprite letterSprite;
    [SerializeField]
    public AudioClip letterAudio;
}

[System.Serializable]
public class LetterDataDictionary : SerializableDict<int, Letter_Data>
{

}

[System.Serializable]
public class DictionaryOfLettersData : SerializableDict<int, LetterDataDictionary>
{

}
```

As you can see every data type is `Serializable`, I believe my problem is the dictionary is getting modified during `OnBeforeSerialize()` probably since am accessing a `Serializable Dictionary` of another object, so to solve this I used a dictionary property.

```
[Serializable]
public class SerializableDict<TKey, TValue> : Dictionary<TKey, TValue>, ISerializationCallbackReceiver
{



  [SerializeField, HideInInspector]
    private List<TKey> keys = new List<TKey>();
    [SerializeField, HideInInspector]
    private List<TValue> values = new List<TValue>();


    public Dictionary<TKey, TValue> serializedDictionary
    {
         get;
        private set;
    }

    public void OnBeforeSerialize()
    {

        foreach (var item in serializedDictionary)
            {
                if (!keys.Contains(item.Key))
                    keys.Add(item.Key);

                if (!values.Contains(item.Value))
                    values.Add(item.Value);
            }
    }

    public void OnAfterDeserialize()
    {
        serializedDictionary = new Dictionary<TKey, TValue>();
            for (var i = 0; i < keys.Count; i++)
            {
                serializedDictionary[keys[i]] = values[i];
            }
    }
}
```

This might not be a problem since it is solved now but am curious if someone could give a hint on what is going on ? Maybe there is something I did not know about with unity's serialization so I would love it if anyone faced the same problem and could help me understand it further, I can not move on without understanding my little hack.

Comment: Please use `unity3d` tag for questions related to Unity game engine. It's generally a good idea to read the tags descriptions before applying them.

Comment: Can you describe problem you're having in more detail than just "getting trouble"?

Comment: Hello @golergka First of all thank you for pointing out my mistake, I did specify the problem, the problem is with the dictionary enumeration it fails at moving to the next value, probably because it is getting modified during serialization, but it functions normally if i define a dictionary field instead of accessing the values through the class itself, so my question was to understand why this happens or what happens during serialization. as I stated it is not a problem it is me asking a question about unity serialization.